# Why does sort -u give different output from sort filename | uniq -u?

Tags: linux, sorting, cat, uniq

I am getting two different results for the following commands. Want to know the difference between those  commands.
I want to list unique lines (remove duplicates)in a file. To sort it out, I used following commands.

```
sort -u filename
```

and

```
sort filename|uniq -u
```

I got two different  results. Can someone explain the difference.

Also tried this command. Got another set of new results apart from the above two.

```
cat filename|uniq -u.
```

Comment: please provide a minimal input file which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also, define the active locale -- sort orders and behavior differ based on localization settings. If you can reproduce the behavior with `export LC_ALL=C`, all the better.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Here is  the dropbox link to download the text file which I tested.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqw19g1wxjsqhxj/abc.txt?dl=0

Comment: @all. try with wc -l command , it will show you the number of lines difference between two commands.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimal

Comment: from uniq manual: Note:  'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.  Also, comparisons honor the
       rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file I use:

```
zsh/6 31167 % cat do_sortowania  
Marcin
Tomek
Marcin
Wojtek
Zosia
Zosia
Marcin
Krzysiek
```

using sort:

```
zsh/6 31168 % sort -u do_sortowania 
Krzysiek
Marcin
Tomek
Wojtek
Zosia
```

but using sort + uniq:

```
zsh/6 31170 % sort do_sortowania|uniq -u
Krzysiek
Tomek
Wojtek
```

Now: two answers:
Short:

```
zsh/6 31171 % sort do_sortowania|uniq -c
      1 Krzysiek
      3 Marcin
      1 Tomek
      1 Wojtek
      2 Zosia
```

Long:
As you can see, `quniq -u` return only lines that appear only one: Krzysiek, Tomek, Wojtek.
Zosia and Marcin apper 3 and 2 times so `uniq -u` ommit them.

P.S.

```
zsh/6 31172 % cat do_sortowania|uniq -u
Marcin
Tomek
Marcin
Wojtek
Marcin
Krzysiek
```

becouse, `sort` should works only on sorted files, so:

```
Marcin
Marcin
Tomek
```

will be `uniq`ued to

```
Marcin
Tomek
```

but

```
Marcin
Tomek
Marcin
```

won't, becouse, sort compare row only to next one, becouse it's belive the file is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Sort with **no duplicate entries** in the list:

```
sort -u filename
```

| does the pipeout of the command sort to uniq, witch with -u, **only print unique lines**

```
sort filename|uniq -u
```

In most cases, this is the **correct option for most users**:

```
sort -u filename
```

for ubuntu information on sort: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sort.1.html